# Conversão de encoding string

Tags: c#, aplicação-web

Tenho a seguinte string 
`Cinto De SeguranÃ§a` 
Como converto ela para que fique como 
`Cinto De Segurança`

Comment: Você esta fazendo uma pagina web?

Comment: sim eu passo isso futuramente via rest para o front, mas tenho que solucionar isso no beck. mas optei pela resposta do rovann pois todas funcionaram mas ele foi o primeiro a responder obrigado a todos !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converta para bytes, e depois para string novamente usando outra codificação:

```
string x = "Cinto De SeguranÃ§a";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(x);
string y = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
Console.WriteLine(y);
```

Coloquei no [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2HYTTM)

Answer (score 5):

Você pode fazer isso de uma maneira bem simples:

```cs
Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Cinto De SeguranÃ§a"));
```

Use o namespace: `System.Text`.

```cs
using System.Text;
```

De acordo com [esta resposta no SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057684), se você estiver utilizando o console, para evitar que a sequência de caracteres não saia de uma forma indesejada use:

```cs
Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

Para que os caracteres saiam corretamente como `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar as classes do `System.Text.Encoding`

```
// Obtém um array de bytes do texto
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes("Cinto De SeguranÃ§a");
// Codifica o obtém a string. Usando UTF8, mas pode usar outros, como ASCII ou Unicode 
string retorno = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Veja funcionando aqui: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5Kw99i